# Scanner Class inputs not ending with delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am getting the desired output but my code hasn't finished running.
I have used "/" as the delimiter for the scanner class and My code is

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);        
scan.useDelimiter("/");
while(scan.hasNext())
{
  System.out.println(scan.next());
}
```

My input that i am giving at the Output window is

```
Input
abcdef/ghijkl/out/

Output:
abcdef
ghijkl
out
```

And the program is still running.

Comment: Are you sure that how many strings(Each string is delimited by '/') you have to read?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner; // headers MUST be above the first class

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
 // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner("abcdef/ghijkl/out/");        
    scan.useDelimiter("/");
    while(scan.hasNext())
        {
          System.out.println(scan.next());
        }
    }
}
```

This Works.

Your problem may be that you are opening a Scanner for the keyboard (System.in), but you aren't storing the value of your keyboard input anywhere. You would probably want to set your input to a variable, like I have always done in classes that taught Java:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
String input = scan.nextLine(); // input: "abcdef/ghijkl/out/"

String[] stringArray = input.split("/");
for(String i : stringArray)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: I removed the last code snippet that I posted. It is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `next()` method. Following is an extract from [Oracle Website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) which states that **This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true**

> **public String next()**
>
> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. *This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true*.

Answer (score -2):

you have to close scan using `scan.close();`

here you will use it as

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);        
scan.useDelimiter("/");
while(scan.hasNext())
{
  System.out.println(scan.next());
  scan.close();
}
```

Comment: Throws an `IllegalStateException`

Comment: never do this, it closes `System.in` and that makes it unavailable for the rest of the life of your program.